# Mouse hover with CartoDB?

Tags: carto

Some of the CartoDB maps online, like [Illustreets](http://illustreets.co.uk/explore-england/) react constantly to mouse hover instead of requiring a click. Is there a way that I can do that with my CartoDB maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its now been added to the GUI check [this](http://blog.cartodb.com/new-features-infowindows-on-hover-and-icons-for-your/) and [this](https://twitter.com/cartoDB/status/468505024520138752)

Answer (score 2):

One of the CartoDB developers just put a great example of this, see http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/8313604

Right now it does take some javascript coding, leveraging cartodb.js. In the future the team hopes to add hover functionality directly to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are some [CartoDB templates developed by Michael Keller](http://blog.cartodb.com/post/47054808317/guest-post-michael-keller-from-newsbeast-labs) that will give you some more hints on how to do the hover with JS.